# Upvoting Stack Overflow answers from DuckDuckGo

Tags: feature-request

The duckduckgo.com search engine very cleverly returns the correct Stack Overflow answer on top of the search results most of the time.

It will be good if you guys can work out with DDG team, so we can upvote correct answers directly from the search results!

---

Also posted it as an issue on [DDG's GitHub page](https://github.com/duckduckgo/duckduckgo/issues/246).

Comment: I get good results from Bing, and I can upvote the result for Bing as well.

Comment: Shouldn't you come to the site to vote on the question as well anyway?

Comment: Or just live on the site and use its inbuilt search function.

Comment: @Bugs Yeah, but Stack Overflow's search sometimes doesn't produce results as good as a search engine.  Additionally, it only searches SO and not the rest of the Internet.

Answer (score 29):

Why?

Stack Exchange sites would need to:

- Check if the user has the privilege to upvote
- If they do, calculate it similar to an API call and let it count on their account
- If they don't, treat it as an anonymous vote
- **Throttle the heck out of it**, since it would be trivial to write a crawler which takes advantage of this exposed system

Did I mention that Stack Overflow (the company) would then have to invest time and money into building this out *and* securing it?

But yes, they *could* do this...or they could just require you to authenticate to the specific Stack Exchange site, which is a much saner system to work with.

Comment: i havent thought about all those requirments ...

Comment: ... plus, voting is supposed to be *informed* about the answer's content. You can't see the full answer in the search results. Not sure this would make sense even if it were easy to do.

Comment: And they'd be building all of that functionality towards the goal of helping users *not* visit their pages.

Comment: @user1019129:  Those requirements are kind of vital when making suggestions.  Thinking about these kinds of things help you understand if a suggestion is going to pan out or not.

Answer (score 6):

DuckDuckNo.

Comment: Holy cow you broke the 100k barrier! Congrats, enjoy your complimentary Jeff & Joel Pee On The Mutilated Corpse Of Experts Exchange waterspout fountain! 7 days delivery to mainland US from date of reaching the score, so better start cleaning up the garden.

Comment: @pekka Garden? That shit is going in the living room.